# Only the third button is working, why not the first two?

Tags: javascript, html

I want all my buttons to change the content.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <script></script>

        <p id="demo">Welcome to</p>

        <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml = "Javascript"'>Click</button>
        <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml = "Javascript"'>Click</button>

        <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javascript"'>Click</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not equal to `innerHtml`

Comment: Typing mistake. Correct `innerHtml` as `innerHTML` like working button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a Typo in your code. you spelled `innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <script></script>

        <p id="demo">Welcome to</p>

        <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javascript"'>Click</button>
        <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javascript"'>Click</button>

        <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javascript"'>Click</button>

    </body>
</html>
```